# Certain html sub-page loaded into div when main index.html is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to load one of my sub-pages into the div tag while website is loaded.

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="content-main">

</div>
```

The important thing is that I want to load certain sub html dokument ONLY when main index.html is loaded.

Comment: You can use jQuery's load function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript onload function when html is loaded it is very easy to use like

```
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.onload = function(){
   //do some thing
}
```